# How to copy sql table with all structure( key constraints) and data to another table?

Tags: c#, sql

is there any way to copy sql table with key constraints(complete structure) and data to another table through command without using sql studio UI.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a good way to ask a question here. Did you try _anything_ so far to solve your problem? Show your effort first so people might show theirs. Please read [FAQ], [ask] and [help] as a start..

Comment: describe properly your question and write WHAT YOU HAVE TRIED SO FAR. which database you are using ?

Comment: i am using sql server 2008. i already tried this command SELECT * INTO DestTable FROM SrcTable. this command cpy only the table data not the constraints. for example if SrcTable one of the column defined as primary key column now after copy that table only the content is copied not the constraints is copied to DestTable. How to copy the constraints also.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the table --> choose "Script table as" --> "Create to" --> "New query editor window". You'll get the create statement. For transporting data then use the insert statement.

```
INSERT INTO table1 SELECT * FROM table2
```

Comment: ups, without using sql studio UI... :)

Comment: Sry i want to do it through pragmatically (c#).

Comment: I think you'll have to compose the query by yourself. Check tables KEY_COLUMN_USAGE and CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE from the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

- Right-click on the database name, then select "Tasks" then click on "Generate Scripts". After that, the Script Wizard opens. Click on "Next".
- Select the Database you want to script.
- Choose the object types. Click on "Next".
- Select the tables.
- Select the Output option for the script.
- Change/Edit the database name to the name you want to execute this script for.

I read this from this [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/664327/Copy-Table-Schema-and-Data-From-One-Database-to-An), It might be more helpful to you.