# Duplicating tables keeping constraints

Tags: sql, database, constraints, primary-key

I am trying to find a solution to my problem. I have a newly created database which I want to move some of the tables from my current to. When I try:

```
SELECT * INTO newDB
FROM oldDB
```

This works for the data, however it does not keep any of the constraints from the original table. After doing some browsing online I came across the `SET IDENTITY_INSERT`however that did not seem to help.

Are there any other methods or ideas that I could try? I need to move around 300 tables.

edit:
I would like to stay away from generating scripts for each of the new tables if possible.

Comment: I don't this there is an easy way to do this. Check this out : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23863982/how-to-copy-sql-table-with-all-structure-key-constraints-and-data-to-another-t

Comment: Thats what I was worried about. Was hoping to do it without having to generate the script for each of the tables. Thanks for the comment

Comment: I don't know of a way to do this without using scripts. If you end up doing it with scripts I did something similar for a few tables using BULK and extracting the data from .CSV documents. I can do an example in answers if you wish

Comment: Continuing my search, it seems like the only way is to generate scripts to do this. Would BULK be easier/faster than generating scripts for each of the tables i need to move?

Comment: I think it would be about the same. BULK reads through a .CSV as if it was a text file. Everything that comes from it is an NVarchar. To use it you need to create a temporary table where all columns are nvarchar values and then when you insert your temporary table in the real table CAST the good values. To make the task quicker you can __Right click on the table --> choose "Script table as" --> "Create to" --> "New query editor window"__ and change all values to nvarchar